# Should I disable CoalescingTimerInterval?

Tags: windows-10, regedit

I'm using win10, and I've been told that disabling timer coalescing will decrease input delay. specifically, I should go to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" in the registry and create a 32-bit dword named CoalescingTimerInterval.

I'm wondering how much less input delay I'd get, and are there any negative side effects to this?

Comment: Who told you that? Have you got a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling timer coalescing can potentially reduce input delay in certain scenarios, but the extent of the improvement and any potential negative side effects can vary depending on your specific hardware configuration and usage patterns. Let's go over the details.

Timer coalescing is a power-saving feature implemented in Windows operating systems, including Windows 10. It works by grouping timer events together to reduce the number of times the CPU needs to wake up from an idle state, thus conserving power. However, this can introduce a slight delay in processing certain time-sensitive tasks, such as user input.

To disable timer coalescing and potentially reduce input delay, you can follow the steps you mentioned in the Windows Registry Editor. Creating a 32-bit DWORD value named "CoalescingTimerInterval" under the specified registry key allows you to set a specific interval in milliseconds (ms) for timer coalescing.

Now, regarding the extent of the improvement and potential negative side effects, it's important to note the following:

1. Input delay reduction: Disabling timer coalescing may help reduce input delay, particularly in situations where you're experiencing noticeable delays when interacting with your system. However, the actual improvement can vary depending on various factors, including your hardware configuration, system workload, and the specific applications you use.
2. Hardware and driver compatibility: While most systems should handle the disabling of timer coalescing without issues, it's worth mentioning that certain hardware components or device drivers may rely on this feature to function optimally. Disabling it might potentially cause compatibility issues, resulting in unexpected behavior or even system instability.
3. Power consumption: Disabling timer coalescing can slightly increase power consumption since the CPU will wake up more frequently to process timer events. Although the impact on power usage is generally negligible, it's worth considering if you prioritize power efficiency.
4. System behavior: Disabling timer coalescing might affect the overall system behavior, potentially leading to different patterns of CPU utilization. In some cases, this could result in increased CPU usage, which might impact overall system performance or battery life, depending on your device.

It's important to understand that the impact of disabling timer coalescing can vary from system to system, and it might not always provide a noticeable improvement in input delay. If you're experiencing significant input delay or latency, it's advisable to explore other optimization options, such as updating drivers, adjusting system settings, or considering hardware upgrades if necessary.

Lastly, before making any changes to the Windows Registry, it's recommended to create a system restore point or backup your registry settings to revert changes if unexpected issues arise.

Comment: Not from chatgpt again. We want to hear ftom you, not a robot.